# I don't understand our proof for "The spectral radius of a normal operator $A$ is equal to the norm of $A$", it's different to what I've found here

Tags: operator-theory, spectral-theory, spectral-radius

Our proof is a little bit different than the proofs I've found here on this forum. I understand the rest of the proof as it's just using the Gelfand-Beurling formula, but the part I don't understand goes like this (that's the first part of the induction to show that $\|A\|^{2^k} = \|A^{2^k}\|$):

$$\|A^4\| = \|A^* A\|^2 = \|(A^* A)^* \ (A^* A)\| = \|(A^*A)(A^*A)\| = \|(A^*)^2 (A)^2\| = \|A^2\|^2$$

I basically don't understand every "
$=$" here. Could someone maybe help me understand this part of the proof step by step?

I think it could maybe have something to do with the fact, that $\|A^* A\| = \|A\|^2$, that multiplying operators could here be commutative and that maybe for some reasons it's true here that $\|A^k \| = \|A\|^k$ for $k$ natural. But still, even assuming those 3 things are true and used here, I don't see where the third "$=$" is coming from.

Comment: I think you should replace $\| A^4 \|$ with $\| A \|^4$ in the beginning. Equality 1+2 employ the $C^*$ property: $\| A^* A\| = \| A \|^2$. Equality 3: $(AB)^* = B^*A^*$. Equality 4: An operator is normal if (by defintion) it commutes with its adjoint. Equality 5: $C^*$ property again.

Comment: @Janik   I don't see how Equality 3 is $(AB)^* = B^* A^*$

Comment: $(A^*A)^* = A^* A^{**} = A^* A$

Comment: @Janik That's only the case if we assume that $A$ is self-adjoint, but what about if $A$ is only normal?

Comment: The above holds for all $A$, independent of whether it is normal, self-adjoint, etc. The identity $A^{**} = A$ is a property of an involution, see e.g. [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C*-algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C*-algebra).

Answer (score 1):

The only things one uses are the C$^*$-identity: $$\tag1\|T\|^2=\|T^*T\|,$$ and that $A^*A=AA^*$, which is normality. That said, I don't understand the steps as written in your question. Here is my take.

- You start with $\|A^4\|=\|A^{*4}A^4\|^{1/2}$ by applying $(1)$.
- By normality this is equal to $\|(A^*A)^4\|^{1/2}$.
- Now we use that $A^*A$ and its square are selfadjoint. Then, using $(1)$ in the second equality,
  $$\|(A^*A)^4\|^{1/2}=\|(A^*A)^{2*}(A^*A)^2\|^{1/2}=\big[\|(A^*A)^2\|^2\big]^{1/2}=\|(A^*A)^2\|.
  $$
- Using that $A^*A$ is selfadjoint and using $(1)$ twice,
  we get
  $$
  \|(A^*A)^2\|=\|(A^*A)^*(A^*A)\|=\|A^*A\|^2=\big(\|A\|^2\big)^2=\|A\|^4.
  $$